# face colors not unique when using 8 indexed vertices

Tags: webgl

Without any code at first let me describe the problem.

I recreated the basic lesson for a rotating cube. Lesson 4 Learning Webgl
http://learningwebgl.com/lessons/lesson04/index.html

The code has 4 vertices listed for each face for a total of 24 vertices. It uses indices to these 24 vertices 0-23 to do a drawElements(...) and it uses a color buffer array with 24 different colors.

So the end result of course is a rotating cube with each face assigned a different color.

What I did was work with the fact that a cube really only has 8 vertices not 24. So I made an array of 8 vertices. And I reworked the position index array to work with indices from 0-7 instead of what was given 0-23. I left the color buffer array alone since I put the same order to the face creation as in the original lesson.

When I completed the drawElements(...), I did have a perfect rotating cube. But the cube is not colored correctly. Each vertex has a single color so only the first eight of the color array elements (out of 24) were used. Basically The top half is one color and the bottom half is another color. And the faces of the cube do not have a unique color.

The question is : is there a way to assign color to vertex indices instead of to vertices?
I am suspecting that I could use gl_vertexID in the shaders, but I thought I'd get some opinions first?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no.

Basically you have tree options for assigning values to vertices:

1. Assign a unique value per vertex. Note that if you want to use a vertex with different values (such as different colors for each face), then there must exist a unique vertex for each 'configuration'
2. Sometimes it is possible to compute the value in the vertex or fragment shader (this will actually work in your case).
3. Use a uniform shader value - this will assign the same value to all vertices (that is clearly not what you want in this case).

For more information I suggest you read my blog-posts about Procedural Mesh Generation in Unity , since it explains the basic concepts:

- http://blog.nobel-joergensen.com/2010/12/25/procedural-generated-mesh-in-unity/
- http://blog.nobel-joergensen.com/2011/04/05/procedural-generated-mesh-in-unity-part-2-with-uv-mapping/

Comment: Thanks for the direct answer. Nice tutorials, by the way. I will work with case two , computing the face color based in the shaders.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to pass per-face data to WebGL.

In WebGL (and OpenGL ES 2) There are two kinds of data that can be passed to the shaders: vertex attributes and uniforms.  Vertex attributes can have a different value for each vertex, and uniform data has a single value that only changes explicitly via one of the uniform*() calls.

When a vertex attribute, say a color, is passed directly from the vertex shader to the fragment shader, it is automatically interpolated by the hardware so that the result is a smooth change of the value (color) over the surface of the resulting triangle.  So to give a triangle a "flat" color, all of the vertices of the triangle need to be given the same color.  Since the vertices will also be part of other triangles that will likely have different colors, the only option is to create a separate vertex entry for each different color of each face that uses the same point.

If you were to use a uniform instead, the uniform would have to be changed as each face is drawn.  This would mean you would have to separate the cube into 6 parts, and make 6 separate drawing calls.  This is much less efficient.  It is well accepted that the "less evil" solution is to have multiple vertex entries as described and use up some extra GPU memory to make the drawing faster.

In other versions of OpenGL there is a function `glVertexAttribDivisor()` that lets you set a vertex attribute that only changes every n vertices.  This can be used to achieve what you are trying to do.  However it is unfortunately not available in WebGL.